# Error "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden for js files in yii

Tags: javascript, yii

In my yii web application, I got an error "like:NetworkError: 403 Forbidden" for some js files and also shows error

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

But these js files are properly included in layout page. How to solve this problem. Please help me.

I included the js files in layout pages like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/assets/js/plugins/pickers/pickadate/picker.date.js"></script>
<!-- Load time picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/assets/js/plugins/pickers/pickadate/picker.time.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

The error is,

[image]

How to avoid this error.

Comment: Please click the "Edit" link below your question and add the relevant code. It's not possible to make even an educated guess without that information.

Comment: The code you posted don't seem related to the forbidden  js .. The 403  error is clear -you don't have the right for  accessing to js files and you don't have declare the refernce for jquery..

Comment: Did you try changing the permission of files ?

Comment: yes... But not working.

Comment: You have to restart some web servers, like Apache, after   increasing file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem like you .
It does have an .htaccess file in it which says "deny from all".
change deny with allow and reset httpd .